# I need help creating a loop for this problem

Tags: c#

I'm having difficulty creating the loop for this problem.

Calculating the income tax requires the app to accumulate all the taxes from all the preceding tax brackets to the
income’s bracket as shown in the table. 
a) Also, you must use loops to solve this problem.

This is what I have so far

```
        int[] upper = { 9525, 38700, 82500, 157500, 200000, 500000, };
        int[] rate = { 10, 12, 22, 24, 32, 35, 37 };
        double tax;
        Write("Please enter your income >> ");
        double income = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < upper.Length; i++)
        {
            if (income <= upper[i])
            {
                tax = income * rate[i];

            }

        }
```

Loop logic should function like this if the income was $100,000

```
IncomeTax = 
  ($ 9,525[upper[0]]) * 10%[rate[0]] 
+ ($38,700[upper[1]] - $9,525[upper[0]]) * 12%[rate[1]] 
+ ($82,500[upper[2]] - $38,700[upper[1]]) * 22%[rate[2]] 
+ ($100,000[income] - $82,500[upper[2]]) * 24%[rate[3]] = $18,289.50[total]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like school project!!

Comment: you don't need else in this case

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: Don't include your code as pictures. Add your code to your question.
Also be specific about your question and don't have multiple questions to one post.

Comment: this will give only last tax if you want all the tax summed up then add previous tax each time in the loop

Comment: Please write a better title...

Answer (score 1):

Too many problems with this little code.

- You are over-writing the "Tax", while you want to sum up the value of all taxes to make one resultant tax
- your condition `income <= upper[i]` to calculate the tax is not proper in this context
- you are not calculating tax on the delta `(upper[i] - upper[i -1])` but on `upper[i]` only
- Your formula to calculate the tax is wrong.
- you should break the loop once you find that your income is less than the slab (upper[i])

But at least I could see your efforts and thus I'm posting one working code for you reference (you may improve it further)

```
        //added , 9999999999 to make the last slab (37%) tends to infinite 
        long[] upper = { 9525, 38700, 82500, 157500, 200000, 500000, 9999999999 };
        int[] rate = { 10, 12, 22, 24, 32, 35, 37 };
        double tax = 0.0;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your income >> ");
        //if income is of double data type, we should convert console into double instead of int
        double income = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double taxCalculatedAmount = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < upper.Length; i++)
        {
            //Note: here I am calculating the delta 
            //which I will use to calculate the tax for the slab.
            double incomeToCalculateTax  =
                upper[i] <= income ? (i == 0 ? upper[i] : upper[i] - upper[i - 1]) : 
                                     (i == 0 ? income : income - upper[i - 1]);

            //Condition which will check if amount on which we have calculated tax is exceeding total amount
            if (income > taxCalculatedAmount)
            {
                //proper formula of calculating tax
                tax += (incomeToCalculateTax * rate[i]) / 100;
                taxCalculatedAmount += incomeToCalculateTax;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Your help definitely pushed me in the right direction. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The following is a self-contained static function calculating the required result. While it probably does not make a difference for the sake of the exercise, in general it is advisable not to use floating point numbers for calculations with currency because you may lose precision when working with large amounts; either convert to the lowest units (cents or whatever) and use integers (or longs), or use decimals as done below.

```
public static decimal IncomeTax(decimal income)
{
    // Only positive income can be taxed
    if (income <= 0M) return 0M;

    // Initialize bracket limits and rate percentages
    int[] brackets = { 0, 9525, 38700, 82500, 157500,
                       200000, 500000, int.MaxValue };
    int[] rates = { 10, 12, 22, 24, 32, 35, 37 };

    // Start with zero tax
    decimal tax = 0M;

    // Loop over tax rates and corresponding brackets
    for (int i = 0; i < rates.Length; i++)
    {
        // Calculate amount of current bracket
        int currBracket = brackets[i + 1] - brackets[i];

        // If income is below lower bound, exit loop
        if (income < brackets[i]) break;

        // If income is between lower and upper bound,
        if (income < brackets[i + 1])
        {
            // adjust bracket length accordingly
            currBracket = income - brackets[i];
        }

        // Add tax for current bracket to accumulated tax
        tax += (rates[i] / 100M) * currBracket;
    }

    // Return result
    return tax;
}
```